# Manejo de variables extraidas desde Json

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins, jira

Estoy rescatando desde la api de jira ciertos datos que necesito comparar más adelante, para esto estoy utilizando las siguientes instrucciones

```
if (CON !=  null){

    println "Se realiza validacion de conflictos en piezas de software"

          DIF = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """ curl -u ${USER_NAME}:${PASSWORD} -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json --data '{"jql":"issuetype not in subTaskIssueTypes() AND Linea_QA in (${LINEA_QA_D}) AND status in (Backlog_Certificacion, Instalacion_en_Certificacion, Testing, Certificacion, QA, Backlog_Instalacion_Certificacion) ORDER BY Linea_QA ","startAt":0,"maxResults":100,"fields":["id","key","customfield_11301"]}' "http://itproyectos.bancofalabella.cl/rest/api/2/search" | jq . """)

          try {

              def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
              def cfg = null
              cfg = jsonSlurper.parseText(DIF)
              println "Todo el JSON\n"+cfg
              println "Branch instalados actualmente en la linea:"+cfg.issues.key
              println "Linea asociada al branch encontrado \n"+cfg.issues.fields.customfield_11301.value
              def key_branch = cfg.collect{it * it}
              println key_branch

          }catch(e1){
              throw e1
              println "Error encontrado\n" + e1
          }
```

[image: Resultado de la ejecución porcion de codigo]

el campo que necesito rescatar desde el json es el "cfg.issues.key" y almacenarlo en una variable que pueda comparar posteriormente, los resultados almacenados en esta variable pueden ser 0 o muchos...

¿Cómo puedo realizar esto último?

EDIT

lo solucione de la siguiente forma

```
              def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
              def cfg = null
              cfg = jsonSlurper.parseText(DIF)
              println "Todo el JSON\n"+cfg
              println "Branch instalados actualmente en la linea:"+cfg.issues.key
              //println "total branch encontrados:"+cfg.total
              println "Linea asociada al branch encontrado \n"+cfg.issues.fields.customfield_11301.value

              def parse = cfg.issues
              def STR = []

              parse.each { STR.add it."key" }

              def int pp = STR.size()
              def int rr = 0

              while(pp>rr){ 
                rr++
              }
```